# How well does Ubuntu perform with an external SATA SSD?

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a macbook air with 120GB internal storage. That's barely enough for MacOS, so I can't dual boot without getting an external SSD. However, I wanted to know if the Ubuntu installation on the external SSD will perform well enough? I plan to connect the drive through USB (2.0). If it helps, [this is the drive](https://www.amazon.in/EVM-128GB-SSD-INCH-SATA/dp/B09B14SHJT?ref_=Oct_d_onr_d_1375379031&pd_rd_w=LsD5c&pf_rd_p=4599172e-6201-4ea0-865b-8d658f9bdd69&pf_rd_r=C6X5ZGT030FD30TEYF59&pd_rd_r=d15b1180-ff2e-42e2-a16c-4a8b20ccd3e6&pd_rd_wg=FJhdQ&pd_rd_i=B09B14SHJT) I'm considering buying. Will this setup be usable? It probably won't be as lightning fast as internal SSD but can I at least use it for programming, watching youtube and zoom school meetings?

Comment: "Well enough" and "usable" are very subjective. It will probably work, but will be painfully slow. Not worth the effort, IMHO.

Comment: Free 25 GB for Ubuntu, and move some of your data out to the SSD instead. The apple operating system as such certainly does not need the full 120 GB.

Comment: Be aware that TRIM for the external SSD might not work over your USB connection.

Comment: I was surprised how well USB3 with SSD worked. But USB2 will be slow. I have used both an old SATA SSD with SATA to USB adapter and a M.2 SATA SSD with adapter case, both have worked very well with USB3.

Comment: I think Mac OS only uses about 30-50Gb, Ubuntu only needs about 20Gb so I’d put both os’s on your ssd and use the external for large files storage. You otherwise risk setting it up to fail with Ubuntu - it’ll never be as satisfactory as an internal drive.

Comment: Ubuntu runs mainly in RAM. If you have 8GB, Ubuntu should run fine. A slow disk will cause programs to open slowly the first time you use them in the session. It will cause data to take time to save.